# Simple .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error, .htpasswd

I tried to create the .htaccess and the .htpasswd whith sulbime text 2, then notepad++, notepad with different encoding and rename my file in filezilla but I still get an Internal server error.
I get my path with the line

Here my .htaccess

```
AuthName "preprod"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/site/preprod/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Here my .htpasswd

```
dev:tJqh/oQHViefU
```

I have no idea how to resolve it ..
My host is OVH

Comment: check your apache error.log

Comment: I haven't any log file on my ftp :/
I don't know where OVH put it

Comment: Ok i find them and it always says : 
[Sun Jul 06 18:05:52 2014] [error] [client 212.198.228.133] [host preprod.mysite.fr] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /home/mysite/preprod/.htpasswd 
Or this:
[Sun Jul 06 18:15:50 2014] [error] [client 212.198.227.133] [host preprod.mysite.fr] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /usr/local/apache2/.htpasswd I don't understant why the my path seems not good. :o How to get it ?

Comment: That means your password file is either not having correct path or wrong permissions.

Answer (score 0):

download a sample file of .htaccess and .htpasswd, and put your code on it and upload it to you webroot. some times you rename a text file with another file extension, it changes file's name only not the extension or file type.